# How to make Vim open empty buffer with CWD set when opening a folder?

Tags: neovim, netrw, startup

At the moment when I run `nvim path/to/folder/` it opens up the netrw window for it (more accurately, the [Dirvish](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish) window for it), I'd like this to not be the case.

Ideal behaviour is that:

- when I do `nvim path/to/file.js` it opens the file, as normal, and
- when I do `nvim path/to/folder/` it opens the normal empty buffer (the one with the copyright statement and so on) but with the CWD set to `path/to/folder/`.

This is basically to mimic a bit more the Atom behaviour, where as soon as I open the folder (usually with `nvim .`)

I can do fuzzy matching for the files right away, Dirvish has bound `Ctrl-p` (my fuzzy match key) to something else so I can't use it in that case.

Comment: Why would you want an empty screen? You are specifically opening a directory with vim. If  you want to change directory, just do `CWD`

Comment: @EnanAjmain as stated in the last paragraph, I want an empty screen so that I can fuzzy search the files right away, at the moment Dirvish taking control of Ctrl-p doesn't permit me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was a misunderstanding of behaviour from my end.

In Atom, one does `atom .` to open the current folder. In `vim`/`nvim`/`vimr` one can simply call it without a path and the current folder will be opened as CWD by default.

So the solution is to simply call the command without any path.

Also, I apologize that the question is a bit badly worded and lacks accurate information.

Comment: Your question mentions using `nvim /path/to/folder`: if you actually need this, you could try `nvim +"cd /path/to/folder"`

Comment: In my defense, it is a bit hard to imagine not knowing to open vim without . as argument when you especially know that one -_-

Answer (score 0):

I know this can be off topic but I'd work around the issue by redefining `vim` in a bash function.
It checks whether the last argument is a file or a directory and acts correspondingly.

The bash version:

```bash
vim() {
    if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then
        # No arguments: just run vim
        /usr/bin/vim
    elif [[ -d ${!#} ]]; then
        # Last argument is directory: just cd there and open vim without a file name
        cd ${!#}
        /usr/bin/vim ${@:1:$#-1} # strip the last argument
        cd -
    else
        # Last argument is not a directory: act same as vim
        /usr/bin/vim $@
    fi
}
```

Still this doesnt work when multiple files are to be opened, like `vim t.txt /usr/share ../README`.

The zsh version

```
vim() {
    if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then
        # No arguments: just run vim
        /usr/bin/vim
    elif [[ -d ${@:$#:1} ]]; then
        # Last argument is directory: just cd there and open vim without a file name
        cd ${@:$#:1}
        /usr/bin/vim ${@:1:($# -1)} # strip the last argument
        cd -
    else
        # Last argument is regular file: just open that file
        /usr/bin/vim $@
    fi
}
```

Comment: FWIW I would use a subshell `(cd dir && vim …)`. Trying to reset the current directory afterward could be error-prone.